# Mac OS C/C++ include issue

Tags: c++, c, include, libgcrypt

I recently installed libgcrypt from Gnu, but even with it inside my /usr/include and /usr/local/include directories I cannot compile a C++ file that includes it. It can't seem to locate the file, despite the fact that I have it in the correct folders. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance of a little sample of the code and the compile command?

Comment: I'm compiling using Xcode, and the only thing that is throwing an error is the line `#include <gcrypt.h>` which says "'gcrypt.h' file not found"

Comment: Are you linking to the libraries properly? Also the actual error would go a long way.